# How to add my protocol into default programs in windows 10?

Tags: windows, registry, protocols, windows-10-universal

Hi I have a new protocol URL:myTest, how can I add it in windows 10 so I can see it listed in default programs? Shall I add it in registry? How/Where exactly could I do that?

I want to associate a program with this protocol.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of app this is? A pure modern app or a converted desktop app?

Comment: Hi it is a UWP app. I figured it out --> It should be in Package.appxmanifest. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The registration for "Default Programs" is in the registry under [`SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#RegisteredApplications). If your application fits one of the [client types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144109(v=vs.85).aspx#_com_reg_elements) then you should point your RegisteredApplications value to `Software\Clients\%ClientType%\%YourCanonicalName%\Capabilities`, otherwise you can use any key like `Software\%YourCompany%\%YourApp%\Capabilities` or `Software\Classes\Applications\%Filename%\Capabilities`.

The most important subkey in your case is [UrlAssociations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#keys_and_values).

You must also register your protocol in [the normal way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

Some of this [changed in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/20/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10122-for-pcs/#sAScxRmIyy5ZJYmE.97) and I would recommend that you test on Windows 7 or 8 as well. "Default Programs" has been deprecated in Windows 10.

You should also register yourself in the [Applications key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#applications) for integration with the "Open with" dialog.

This is the way it works for pure desktop apps, I'm not sure what happens if you convert a desktop app to UWP. Modern apps [declare their protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986920.aspx) in the manifest.